# Eagle - 6 Layer Via pairing error + bga fanout

Tags: pcb, eaglecad, pcb-layers, bga, autorouter

I'm trying to manually fanout 5 bga's on my 6 layer board. Tried using Eagle's default Auto BGA router and kept coming up with problems regarding my additional layers being used but not enabled, I managed to fix this problem for my bottom ground layer but wasn't able to fix this for my power, middle signal & top ground layers however, so I just ended up doing this manually.

My 1st problem I'm encountering is the via pairing within the DRC layers tab.
I've got it set to 6 layers and want to be use the following pairings:

- 1-2
- 1-3
- 14-16
- 15-16
- 1-14
- 3-16

I can add everything perfectly fine except the 2 last pairings (1-14 & 3-16). I can add one or the other; however if I add the other then I get an error either for invalid blind via or unexpected ':'

For example if I add the 3-16 pairing I will get the following setup string:  ([3:[2:[1*2*3*14*15*16:3]:15]:14])
However if I then add 1-14 I get the following below error:
[image]

If anyone knows how to get around this error and allow me to use all of the above pairings in one go, would be most appreciated.

My board stackup is as follow:

- Top     (1)
- TGround (2)
- Middle  (3)
- Power   (14)
- BGround (15)
- Bottom  (16)

Where Top, Middle and Bottom are signal layers whilst all signal lines relating to power will be located on the Power layer.

My 2nd problem I'm faced with is that out of the 5 bga's I'm working on 2 of them are completely different pitches for their ball arrays.

With one being 0.5mm & the other being 0.42mm (The other 3 bga's being 0.65mm)
Which settings within DRC do I need to change so I can fanout the smallest bga?

An sub-question to this I'd like to ask how I would be able to manually place micro-via's? The auto bga router apparently does it but after scouring the web/autodesk eagle forums I've found no posts on how to manually place them.

Thank you for help @Tom Carpenter. I did manage to get a hold of a product specialise from AutoDesk who provided me with the following setup string: [14:[3:[2:(1+2+3+14+15+16):15]:14]:3]

My question to ask regarding this string as its purely 5 cores. Would it be possible at all to incorporate prepreg into 1:2, 3:14 & 15:16 or would this create an impossible to build design?

Comment: maybe?  [2 : (1 + (2 ∗ 3) + (14 ∗ 15) + 16) : 15]   : p ∗ q means that layer p and q are combined with a core, while p + q means that these two layers are combined with prepreg. () signifies buried and through vias, while [a : ... : b] signifies blind vias

Comment: Question - have you checked with a board house that they can even make such a stackup? I don't think your desired stackup can be manufactured.

Comment: @TomCarpenter, I should think that stackup can be manufactured: See Aerospace article: https://aerospacepal.com/6-layer-pcb-stackup-emi-design/
Also the fabhouse I'm currently using is PCBWay. You can view their fabrication capabilities here: https://www.pcbway.com/capabilities.html

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I understand the *+() & [a:...:b] stuff pretty fine. I tried your suggestion and it results in an unexpected ? referring to the * between 2 & 3

Comment: @Dragonfly3r I wasn't questioning your layer use, but rather that PCB houses to build vias that cross over like that.// Buried and blind vias have to be built by drilling the cores in stages. For example your 1:2 and 15:16 requirement means that those two must be cores. That means that the 3:14 must be a core, with the remaining two as prepreg.// However because 2:3 is prepreg, that means that you cannot have a via going 1:3 - because they wouldn't be able to drill it. You couldn't have 14:16 for the same reason. Next, 1:14 is possible, but not at same time as 3:16 as they cross over.

Comment: @TomCarpenter, I see now, hmm. Is there a problem with having it all core layers?
As you mentioned 1:2 & 15:16 & must be cores; however if I am to get 1:3 , 14:16 I wouldn't be able to make these if I used prepreg, so these have to also be cores.

Regarding the crossing problem is there a way I could get around this? Or could I use buried via's perhaps?

Comment: Thinking further, I suppose it 2:3 and 14:15 were cores, with the 1:2, 3:14, and 15:16 being prepreg, you may be able to achieve something close to what you want if they can do depth controlled laser drilling of the outer prepreg layers. Essentially they make the 2:3 and 14:15 holes by drilling the cores. Then use a laser to drill 1:2 vias directly on top. You'd end up with a sort of hybrid via of 1:2 on top of 2:3. You'd have to check with PCBWay if they can do that.

Comment: That would give you `[2:(1+(2*3)+(14*15)+16):15]`

Comment: You could also do `[2:(1+((2*3)+(14*15))+16):15]` if you want the 2:15 buried via as well.

Comment: Correct me if wrong but would be then looking at the likes of say 2 blind bias for 1:2 & 15:16 and then the other layers would simply be connected via buried bias or an I looking at this complexly wrong?

Comment: Essentially yes. They'd build a 4-layer stackup of 2*3+14*15 as a standard build first. This would become the centre of the PCB so its vias would become buried. They then add an additional prepreg layer on each side to make 6-layer, which is laser drilled to add the 1:2 and 15:16 blind vias.

Comment: Okay the proposed string worked as needed however still can't seem how I can work out the 1:14 & 3:16 I guess I could use buried bias from 3:15 and 2:14 or could use a single buried from 3:14